# The meaning of もしかして

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of もしかして？ Sometimes I got it on my Japanese novel (Japanese people have given it to me for free), and on films I watched. But, I don't know what is the meaning of that.

Comment: http://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/2735/

Comment: Welcome to JLSE!  Unfortunately, we do not function as a bulk translation service.  To facilitate your learning, along with the learning of others, please give us your best attempt at translation.  If you are after a translation only, HiNative is a great resource (worth a Google at least.)  Before asking questions on this site, we request you become familiar with what we consider to be on and off topic questions.  You can research that here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -2):

It means "in case" or "perhaps". 
If used at the beginning of a sentence it meanse "in case" or "if".
As a reply to a question is means "perhaps".